What are Steam's storage locations for soundtrack covers?
Steam's soundtracks don't store their covers all in the same place, like, for example, LOST EPIC MINI SOUNDTRACK
I found most of the covers that appear when playing soundtracks in Steam in:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\music\\_database\covers

But not all of them. LOST EPIC MINI is one of the ones I can't find yet.
Which should look like:

Where are these stored?

Looking at that path for my computer, I have a lot of cover images in there for soundtracks I don't own. I don't think it's necessarily the saved files for the installed soundtracks. Have you tried Browse Local Files for LOST EPIC? At least some of my soundtracks have covers inside that folder.

@qazmlpok - Yes. The only thing in the folder is the music. I also chose that example because it's free, so you can test it if you want.

You mentioned "playing in a non-Steam player" in your (now edited) title, but make no reference to it in your post. Was it the case that the cover of every soundtrack played through a music player other than Steam's that was stored outside of the path you mention wouldn't show up? (In a sense, a way of telling where the cover's location was?)

@Joachim - Well, sometimes playing a MP3 song using VLC instead of Steam, and it would have the cover appear as the art for the song, and for some MP3-s, it didn't. I clearly couldn't get a copy of the Cover by pulling it out of those non-art MP3-s, so I wondered where I could get the art.

The picture you are looking at is the "album cover" image for the soundtrack app. As the other answer mentions, the soundtrack itself might not contain this image.
The easiest way to get a copy is:

Find the soundtrack's "app" on SteamDB, in this case: https://steamdb.info/app/1478510/
Scroll down to Album Assets
There should be a key called album_cover. click the linked value
You should now be looking at the album cover image, as displayed in Steam's music player.

If you want to know where this is on your hard drive, it is in the directory %LOCALAPPDATA%\Steam\htmlcache\cache once you have loaded the album in the music player in the Steam app. Steam's entire user interface is now effectively an embedded copy of the Chrome browser, so this directory is a Chrome browser cache. You can use a tool like ChromeCacheView to examine the binary files there, then you can search for the AppID among the cached URLs (e.g. find URLs containing /1478510/) and extract them to find which one is the cover art.

As far as I can tell, artwork may be bundled at the developer/publisher's discretion. There is no guarantee there is quality or standalone artwork associated with a soundtrack
Soundtracks may include cover art within the same place as the music itself. If so, you can browse the files by going to "Browse Local Files" either within the music player or by right clicking the item in the library, and expanding the "manage" context item.
SteamDB will list the included files for a game/soundtrack if you select the latest "depot". For example, https://steamdb.info/depot/1478512/ - the mp3 files are mentioned, but there is no bundled cover art.
Soundtracks may include artwork within the music database folder mentioned in the question. I have no idea what this folder actually is, as it includes artwork for soundtracks I do not own.
Images that appear within the library will be included in the path C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\appcache\librarycache. This is not just soundtracks; it will include everything in your steam library, and all variants of the images that appear within the steam client.
The filename will be the steam asset id, followed by suffixes for the type of file. For the LOST EPIC MINI SOUNDTRACK linked in the question, these would be 1478510_header.jpg, 1478510_library_600x900.jpg, etc.  (as an aside, according to irfanview, some of these files are misnamed PNGs)
These are the files that actually appear within the steam library, and thus have been resized, framed, and likely compressed. If the soundtrack bundles the artwork, it will likely be higher quality. But this appears to be the only guaranteed way to get artwork associated with an item.

Sorry, but can't be, unless there's multiple causes and one of the many causes is Steam makes the cover art by combining multiple jpgs and such together.
Nothing with 1478510 matches the cover art image I just gave, unless Steam, just for Lost Epic, is cutting off "1478510_library_600x900" and putting "1478510_logo" on it, but that's not how other soundtracks that have similar "missing" cover arts would work.

It can't be composite; _600x900 doesn't have the detail to create the resulting image. It has too many artifacts. library_hero doesn't include enough of the "square" image to work either. Unfortunately, those are the only files that were modified when I added the soundtrack to my library, so I have no idea where the files would be. Unless they're just in assets.vdf (same folder) - but mine is only 100kb, which is too small for images.

Thanks for all that work! May we solve the mystery soon!
